# Cannot connect to parity JSONRPC from local machine

Tags: parity, json-rpc, ethereumj

Here is my parity config:

```
[rpc]
disable = false
port = 8545
interface = "all"
cors = ["*"]
apis = ["web3", "eth", "pubsub", "net", "parity", "parity_pubsub", "traces", "rpc", "shh", "shh_pubsub"]
hosts = ["none"]


[footprint]
tracing="on"
pruning="fast"
pruning_memory=100000
```

For some reason, my connection is always refused when I try and connect to the RPC API like so:

```
curl --data '{"method":"trace_replayBlockTransactions","params":["0x2ed119",["trace"]],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8545
```

What am I missing here? I thought this would be fairly straightforward...

Answer (score 1):

As per https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-trace-module#the-ad-hoc-tracing-api in order to perform certain trace methods.

> your node must be in archive mode or the transaction should be within the most recent 1000 blocks.

specifically, your config has `pruning="fast"` in the footprint section where it should be `pruning="archive"` for this method to work.

Comment: two comments: 1) Why am I getting "connection refused" though? 2) I have the pruning_memory set, I would think it would store as many states as it could in that memory (not just 1000 blocks worth)?

Comment: 1) Could you add the exact error you're getting to your question? I'm  actually not certain the wildcard works in the `cors` setting the way you expect it does; "all" is probably what you want (albeit that is insecure).

2) It's more the case that tracing doesn't work with pruning at all, hence pruning needs to be set to "archive".

Comment: 1) The exact error is `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8545: Connection refused`. 2) Why not, I mean it can obviously work for the last 1000 blocks, why not for an arbitrary number? What happens when you set tracing="on" and pruning="fast"? Shouldn't the node know how to handle that kind of a situation.